# pass by reference & assign value to a pointer of pointer of struct

Tags: c, function, struct, malloc, pass-by-reference

I have a struct `MY_TYPE`:

```
struct MY_TYPE {
    boolean flag;
    short int xyz;
};
```

I have another struct `MY_DATA` which has a field with type of pointer to the above struct:

```
struct MY_DATA {
    MY_TYPE *m_type;
    double value;
};
```

I have a function which takes a **pointer to pointer of** `MY_DATA` as parameter:

```
getData(struct MY_DATA **m_data) {
    // create a MY_TYPE pointer & assign value to its field
    struct MY_TYPE *m_type_tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct MY_TYPE));
    m_type_tmp -> xyz = 123;

    // I try to assign a value to the MY_TYPE field of m_data,
    // there is no compiler error, but run time error "bad access"
    (** m_data).m_type = m_type_tmp;
}
```

I call above function by:

```
struct MY_DATA *data;
get_data(&data);
```

The compiler doesn't complain anything, but when run my code, I get "Bad access" on the last line of code of function `get_data(...)`, how come?

Comment: How do you call the function? Please learn how to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: When you call `get_data`, where do the variable `data` point? You *do* make it point somewhere valid before you call `get_data`? Like calling `malloc` and assigning the returned pointer to `data`? Or are you supposed to call `malloc` for the `MY_DATA` structure in the `get_data` function? Lastly, `get_data` or `getData`?

Comment: Also, and to nitpick a little, technically C doesn't have pass by reference. It can only be *emulated*. :)

Comment: Do you have a typedef MY_TYPE for "struct MY_TYPE" ? Because I see it referenced in MY_DATA as "MY_TYPE" only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you pass the address of an uninitialized pointer, you must allocate the structure `MY_DATA` as well:

```
void getData(struct MY_DATA **m_data) {
    // create a MY_TYPE pointer & assign value to its field
    struct MY_TYPE *m_type_tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct MY_TYPE));
    m_type_tmp->flag = 0;
    m_type_tmp->xyz = 123;

    // allocate the MY_DATA structure:
    *m_data = malloc(sizeof(*m_data));
    // Initialize all members
    (*m_data)->m_type = m_type_tmp;
    (*m_data)->value = 0;
}
```

It would be simpler to have the function return a pointer to the allocated structure:

```
struct MY_DATA *getData(void) {
    // create a MY_TYPE pointer & assign value to its field
    struct MY_TYPE *m_type_tmp = malloc(sizeof(*m_type_tmp));
    m_type_tmp->flag = 0;
    m_type_tmp->xyz = 123;

    // allocate the MY_DATA structure:
    struct MY_DATA *m_data = malloc(sizeof(*m_data));
    // Initialize all members
    m_data->m_type = m_type_tmp;
    m_data->value = 0;
    return m_data;
}
```

And invoke it this way:

```
struct MY_DATA *data = get_data();
```

Comment: Your answer immediately point out the cause of my problem, yes, I need to allocate heap for MY_DATA since it is not initialized. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> getData(struct MY_DATA ** m_data)

You don't need pointer to pointer to `MY_DATA`, pointer to `MY_DATA` would be suffice.

Then instead of `(** m_data).m_type = m_type_tmp;` you can write:

`m_data->m_type = m_type_tmp;`

Also these are incorrect:

```
struct MY_DATA *data;  // <-- you haven't initialized the pointer
get_data(&data);
```

You can fix that by:

```
struct MY_DATA data = {0};
get_data(&data);
```

Comment: @chqrlie I mentioned that "pointer to MY_DATA would be suffice", so `m_data` is pointer to `MY_DATA`

Comment: OK, but your proposition implements different semantics.  returning the pointer would be a better alternative.

Comment: the get_data() function is from 3rd party, I cannot change that. It would be nice to have a solution without changing the get_data(...) function signature.

Comment: I see - perhaps have a look at chqrlie answer below

Answer (score 0):

pass by reference means you are passing the value through the reference of other variable while pass by value means you are passing the value either string, float , character or boolean.